# How to best document a replication configuration?

Tags: sql-server-2008, documentation, replication, database-replication

I am looking for suggestions for the best way to document a replication configuration.

Currently the documentation is done in Excel (this sucks), where each dB has a tab & each table is listed in the corresponding dB tab, with how it is replicated to/from the data center...etc.

What is the best way (dynamic creation would be GREAT) to do this?

Comment: documentations? some shops would be envious of yous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to look at data from system tables and use them for documentation

Which objects in the database are published?

Publish DB

- SELECT * FROM sysarticles
- SELECT * FROM syspublications

Distribution DB

- Use Distribution
- GO
- SELECT * FROM distribution..mspublications

SubscriberDB

- USE SubscriptionDB
- SELECT * FROM MSsubscriptions
- SELECT * FROM MSsubscriber_info

Hope it Helps.